# Modify Pie Charts (delete the labels)

Tags: diagrams, datatool

I am totally new to LaTeX and `pgfplots`,... I copied an example for pie charts from another blog. The problem: I don't want the labels in my pie chart. Could you please help me?

This is what I have already (H_S_3 is the name of my plot):

```
\DTLloaddb{H_S_3}{H_S_3.txt}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering

%colours
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{1}{black!50}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{2}{pink}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{3}{green!25}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{4}{blue!70}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{5}{black!15}
\DTLsetpiesegmentcolor{6}{pink!92}

%sans-serif:
%\renewcommand*{\DTLdisplayinnerlabel}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
%\renewcommand*{\DTLdisplayinnerlabel}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\DTLpiechart{
    variable=\quantity,
    %innerlabel={\DTLpiepercent\%},
    %outerlabel={\name\ (\DTLpievariable)},
    }
    {H_S_3}{%
\name=Serotyp,\quantity=Anzahl}
%Legende
\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}
\DTLforeach{H_S_3}{\name=Serotyp}{\DTLiffirstrow{}{\\}%
\DTLdocurrentpiesegmentcolor\rule{10pt}{10pt} &
\name
}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

How can I delete the numbers from my pie chart?

my preamble:

```
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{a4paper,left=28mm,right=28mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm} 
\usepackage{acronym}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{datapie}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}

%PGF Plots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Please complete your code with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Please don't break the code into different parts in your question; instead, edit your question to turn your code into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Note that you're not actually using `pgfplots` here, which doesn't have features for making pie charts. `datapie` is a part of the `datatool` bundle, and is not related to `pgfplots`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the formatting of the number with the `innerlabel` key. Note in your example that there is a commented line that says

```
%innerlabel={\DTLpiepercent\%},
```

Change this to

```
innerlabel={},
```

and the numbers will be removed.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Name,Quantity
"Apples",30
"Pears",25
"Lemons,Limes",40.5
"Peaches",34.5
"Cherries",20
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{datapie}
\DTLloaddb{\jobname}{\jobname.csv}
\begin{document}
\DTLpiechart{
    variable=\quantity,
    innerlabel={},  % <-- 
    }
    {\jobname}{%
\name=Name,\quantity=Quantity}
\end{document}
```

[image]